# i would like to create 60GB video NFT, is it possible?

Tags: nft

Is it a matter of price?
I would like to know what is the process to do that.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The size of the video is immateriall.

The general process would be to store the video in an unambiguous location. IPFS is a favorite choice because the content of the video will generate a unique fingerprint (hash) that doubles as the filename/url. Any change to any pixel in any frame would generate a completely different hash.

The NFT would store the hash rather than the 60GB contents. The hash is always 32 bytes regardless of the size of the input file that generates it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob.

i saw that there is a "GAS fee" for processing the file to the Eth blockchain, is it a property of the file size?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer ;-)

Comment: Ive edited the anser if you can help :)

Comment: You've changed the question from requiring a yes/no answer to one requiring a tutorial... :-)

Comment: I'm thinking "troll"

Comment: Ok, thanks again Rob

i didn't mean to "troll" or anything, I'm just starting to get familiar with those terms such as Gas fee and NFT so it might seem like i was "trolling" because I'm still a bit confused.
 Anyway, thanks again, I'll try to figure it out from here

Answer (score 1):

Given Rob's answer, you now know the question isn't *"How much would it cost to store 60 GB?"*

But here's the answer to that question anyway...

---

The current price of ETH is ~$1650.

The Yellow Paper states that storing a 256-bit (32-byte) word costs 20,000 gas.

Average gas price is currently ~160 Gwei. That's 160 x 20,000 Gwei per 32 bytes, which is 3,200,00 Gwei, which is 0.0032 ETH, which is $5.30.

1 GB is 1,073,741,824 bytes, so there are 33,554,432 32-byte words. As above, each of these words costs $5.30, so each GB costs (5.3 * 33554432) = $177,838,000 at current prices.

60 GB would therefore cost ~$10,670,309,376.

That's $10.7 billion... (and you'd have to split the file across a lot of blocks)

Comment: Ok, then could you explain how to make an ICO that will raise 10B$?

Comment: If I could then I'd probably be lying on a beach in some exotic location instead of writing this response... :-|